# dplyr loading issues : Error in unloadNamespace(package)

Tags: r, dplyr

I just updated my R library Im not sure if that is the issue or something else

this is the error

```
library(dplyr)
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  Package ‘dplyr’ version 1.0.4 cannot be unloaded:
 Error in unloadNamespace(package) : namespace ‘dplyr’ is imported by ‘tidyr’, ‘broom’ so cannot be unloaded
```

when I tried to load tidyverse

l

```
ibrary(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
 no such symbol C_collapse_array in package /usr/lib64/R/library/jsonlite/libs/jsonlite.so
```

Comment: It seems like you are trying to attach the updated versions in session with other packages already attached using the old versions. Do you get these error messages if you try attaching `dplyr` after you restart R?

Comment: after i restarted it works at the same time few other packages are now showing error